# LED & Camera always ON

Tags: camera, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, led, light

I'm trying to open the device camera an activate immediately the LED light of that device (android/iOS).

I've tried the appcelerator ti.media events but didn't work, neither this module: [Ti.Light](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.Light).

Found this on this link [activate-iphone-4-led-light](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/43721/activate-iphone-4-led-light)

> Hey guys!
>
> For the flash stuff you have to check the property:
>   Ti.Media.cameraFlashMode (case sensitive)
>
> To change it you can use Ti.Media.setCameraFlashMode(PARAM) .
>
> PARAM could be: Ti.Media.CAMERA_FLASH_OFF , Ti.Media.CAMERA_FLASH_ON,
>   Ti.Media.CAMERA_FLASH_AUTO
>
> Unfortunately you can’t start the led and use it as a torch, you can
>   only control the camera flash handling (on, off, auto) while taking a
>   photo.

There is any module that allow to use the led light all the time? I just need this while the camera is opened.

**UPDATE 1#:**

I’m trying to use your ts.camera widget, that have the embed camera and flash methods:

- [github - ts.camera](https://github.com/TheSmiths-Widgets/ts.camera)
- [gittio - ts.camera](http://gitt.io/component/ts.camera)

But there is no method switchFlashlight() in “pw.custom.androidcamera” module, this widget works?

- [github - Ti-Android-CameraView](https://github.com/brownemint/Ti-Android-CameraView)
- [gittio - pw.custom.androidcamera](http://gitt.io/component/pw.custom.androidcamera)

**UPDATE 2#:**

In order to find a workaroud, I've added this flashlight module, and I'm trying to call it before or after showing the camera, but I think that it's not possible to have 2 camera activities at the same time.

This is my index.js file:

```
if(OS_ANDROID) {

    flash = require('dk.napp.flashlight');

    if(!flash.isFlashLightOn()) flash.turnFlashLightOn();

    camera = require('pw.custom.androidcamera');

    view = camera.createCameraView();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[DEBUG] :  CameraViewProxy: Camera not available
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy: Camera is null. Make sure
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy: is in you tiapp.xml file.
```

This is my tiapp.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.params"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two modules might do the job:

http://gitt.io/search?q=flash

Although it could well be that activating the device camera will override the control over the flash light.

Comment: I've tried that android module some time ago, but there is no download link, I've downloaded the ZIP from git repository and create a folder: 'com.kangacoders.tiflashlight' inside 'Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/' and create a folder '0.1' with all module files inside the 'com.kangacoders.tiflashlight' folder, but I'm allways getting this error: Requested module not found. 

The thing is that there is no TORCH method on Ti.Media

Comment: I've downloaded 2 widgets, but I need to add a feature to each one: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032354/edit-a-titanium-module-ios-android)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032354/edit-a-titanium-module-ios-android]

Comment: @RicardoPereira please follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Using_a_Module to manually install modules. TL;DR drop the ZIP in the project root and add it to the tiapp.xml

Comment: I was facing some trouble after downloading the eclipse resources for module development, the appcelerator was stopping automatically at the start, but it's solved now, I've created one module for android with part of my android studio project, and it worked fine :) thanks for your time

Comment: I've also contact brownemint, creator of https://github.com/brownemint/Ti-Android-CameraView to add that feature.

Comment: The ideal solution for me it's the Ti.Media.showCamera() with the overlay view, the only thing that it's missing is the TORCH mode to the flash mode property, so I've created a JIRA ticket for this: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4401