# Use same activity twice at the same time

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using Appcelerator Studio, my project has 2 different modules, but those share the same android permissions (defined at tiapp.xml), one for embed the camera inside a UIView and other to enable the flashlight in Torch mode, both need to use the camera permissions.

I don't think that there is a solution for this without changing the module itself, right?

This is the log that I'm getting:

```
[DEBUG] :  CameraViewProxy: Camera not available
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy: Camera is null. Make sure
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
[ERROR] :  CameraViewProxy: is in you tiapp.xml file.
```

The issue that depends on this:

[LED & Camera always ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896617/led-camera-always-on/37027649)

Comment: I couldn't even understand what is question is about.

Comment: I'm using Appcelerator. I've updated the question

Comment: I don't think you can share a manifest between modules. Maybe Appcelerator is different, though.

Comment: Each module have is own manifest, but the manifest it's placed in the main configuration file (tiapp.xml). What's happening here is that both modules are using the android camera hardware and the surface view at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A camera is a complex object with many features -- but each camera is treated as a whole by the API (i.e. most devices have exactly two Camera objects.)

It sounds like you are attempting to use one of the features (the flash/torch LED) from one part of your program, and a different feature (taking a picture or at least a preview) from another part of your program.

A camera doesn't work that way.

When you call the `Camera camera = Camera.open();` method successfully, you own the entire camera until you call `camera.release();`  Any other call to `Camera.open();` will fail until you release the camera.

Thus you need to find a way to share the single opened Camera object between your modules.

A simple approach would be to use a Singleton pattern.  [There are other options but they tend to be more complex.]

Whatever you do you need to ensure that if your application is not "on top" you have released the camera for use by other applications.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thougth, I've edited a Titanium Module and added the feature that I need, but when I try to create a module package it throws this error: Error within Debug UI: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. I've created a question about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057251/cant-package-a-titanium-modude